# Absolute Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( -1 \right)^{n-1}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine divergence, absolute convergence, or conditional convergence for:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( -1 \right)^{n-1}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}.$$

And using the alternating series test it meets the 3 criteria for convergence - positive, decreasing and $\lim_{x \to \infty } =0.$

Does that mean it converges absolutely?
Can I use the AST to determine absolute convergence?  And if not, what tests can be used to test for absolute convergence?

Comment: Of course not ! It only mean that it converges, but not necessarily absolutely. Obviously it doesn't converges absolutely since $\frac{e^{1/n}}{n}>\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AST conditions being satisfied means that the original alternating series converges, but does not imply that the series converges absolutely.

Indeed, for your example, absolute convergence fails by the [Limit Comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test):  , because $\frac{\frac{exp\left({\frac{1}{n}}\right)}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1,\ \sum\frac{1}{n}\ $ diverges and therefore $\sum\frac{exp\left({\frac{1}{n}}\right)}{n}$ diverges also. Alternatively, you can use the [Direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) to prove that the series $\sum\frac{exp\left({\frac{1}{n}}\right)}{n}$ diverges.

Finally, a series converges conditionally if the series itself converges but does not converge absolutely. Therefore your series is an example of a conditionally converging series.